# WF 4.0 communicate with host when custom activity fires event

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I building a WF 4.0 application that edits some files, then copies then to another directory. Some of the files are large - in the range of 1 -4 gigs. So I would like to give the copy progress back to the user.

Im using the Microsoft Sync framework for copying the files, and it has an event that fires which contains the percentage copied for the file.

I cannot find a straight forward way to communicate this back to the host besides making a service - and that seems overkill.

I am fairly new to WF4.0, so I may have over looked something really obvious, but after a lot of searching I cant find a straight forward solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [Workflow Instance Extensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patcarna/archive/2010/01/19/windows-workflow-4-0-workflow-instance-extensions.aspx). You create a class that implements the [IWorkflowInstanceExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.hosting.iworkflowinstanceextension.aspx) interface and add a method to send progress notifications:

```
class MyExtension : IWorkflowInstanceExtension
{
    IEnumerable<Object> GetAdditionalExtensions()
    {
        return null;
    }

    void SetInstance(WorkflowInstanceProxy instance)
    { }

    public void SetProgress(int progress)
    {
        // implementation of your method can communicate with the user
    }
}
```

Before running the workflow you add the extension to your host, e.g. [WorkflowApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication%28VS.100%29.aspx):

```
myWorkflowApplication.Extensions.Add(myExtension);
```

Inside the activity you can then access this extension and invoke its methods to send the progress information out of the workflow:

```
context.GetExtension<MyExtension>().SetProgress(progress);
```